# What is the Sink protocol in swift?

Tags: swift

The Swift header has the Sink protocol defined as

```
protocol Sink {
    typealias Element
    func put(x: Element)
}
```

What is the Sink protocol, what should it be used for regarding Swift and Cocoa design patterns?

The only thing that I can tell that implements this protocol is

```
struct IntEncoder : Sink {
    var asInt: UInt64
    var shift: UInt64
    func put(x: CodeUnit)
}
```

Comment: the protocol now appears to be empty.

Answer (score 6):

A sink (as in "kitchen sink") represents the consumer side of a producer/consumer pair. It's an abstract interface that merely accepts some sort of input. Anything that produces objects can therefore be given a `Sink` as a way to deliver the objects. This is the least amount of knowledge the producer needs to have about the consumer to pass the objects.

Queues and sets are examples of simple sinks that just store the input. A network connection or a logger could act as sinks that immediately process the input.

Comment: note: this is also a concept present in nodejs: http://bl.ocks.org/joyrexus/10026630 (ps - I'm not the author, nor do I know the author of that post :)

Comment: not sink as in Kitchen sink, but sink as in sinkhole, time-sink, converse is source.

Comment: Sure, those too, but why not kitchen sink? Those are all named for the same concept.